# XML Deserialization with dynamic fields

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Say I have the following xml:

```
<rootelement>
    <childone>val1</childone>
    <childtwo>val2</childtwo>
    <childthree>val3</childthree>
</rootelement>
```

To deserialize it into an object I'd normally have something like this:

```
public class rootelement{
    public string childone,childtwo,childthree;
}
```

That all works, but now I want to find out if I can have the child node names stored in an array or something so I can manage my fields more easily, and use this array to populate the keys in a `List` of `KeyValuePair` eg:

```
string[] fieldnames={"childone","childtwo","childthree"};
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> fields=new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
for(int i=0;i<fieldnames.Length;i++){
    fields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(fieldnames[i],""));
}
```

And the last step would be for deserialization to populate the values.
It doesn't have to be a `List` of `KeyValuePair` specifically, anything that I could apply the same concept to would work.

Is something like this possible? If so, please assist me with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was the following:

```
public class MyXmlRoot{

private string[] allowedTags={"tagA","tagB","tagC"};

[XmlAnyElement]
public List<XmlElement> children = new List<XmlElement>(); //populated after serialization

public string GetValueByKey(string key){
  return children.Find(k => k.Name == key).InnerText;
}

public void UseTags(){
    for(int i=0;i<allowedTags.Length;i++){
        Console.WriteLine(allowedTags[i]+" = "+GetValueByKey(allowedTags[i]));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you need to deserialize manually.
One of the optoins to do that is using XDocument:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    class Children
    {
        public string one { get; set; }
        public string two { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlstr = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<rootelement>
  <childone>val1</childone>
  <childtwo>val2</childtwo>
  <childthree>val3</childthree>
  <children1>
    <children2>
      <one>val1-1</one>
      <two>val1-2</two>
      <three>val1-3</three>
    </children2>
  </children1>
</rootelement>";

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);

        string[] fieldnames = { "childone", "childtwo", "childthree" };
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> fields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (string i in fieldnames)
        {
            XElement elem = xml.Root.XPathSelectElement(i);
            if (elem != null)
            {
                fields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i, elem.Value));
            }
        }

        // Debug
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> f in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }

        // Try to fill specific object's properties with using reflection

        string parentPath = "children1/children2";
        string[] names = { "one", "two", "three" };
        Children childrenFields = new Children();
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Children).GetProperty(name);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                XElement elem = xml.Root.XPathSelectElement(parentPath + "/" + name);
                if (elem != null)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(childrenFields, elem.Value, null);
                }
            }
        }

        // Debug
        Console.WriteLine("Children one: {0}, two: {1}",
            childrenFields.one, childrenFields.two);
    }
}
```

This code uses `System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement` extension method to find the target XML element by using XPath to support more complex XML document, such as `children1` element in my example.